# Arcmap 10 Dot Net SDK Installation Issues

Tags: arcmap, .net, visual-studio

We have had Arcmap 10 installed on our machines for about a month now and all seems to be well.  I ran into an issue yesterday when I tried to install the Developer SDK for .NET.  An error message shows up stating that I need to have a supported version of Visual Studio installed before the install can continue.

We do have Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Sp1 Professional installed as well as .NET 3.5 framework.  Visual Studio and Arcmap both work just fine.  Has anyone else ran into this problem or know of a solution?  I have put in a help desk request with ESRI, and will post here if I get an answer from them.

Comment: Did you try running a repair on the VS install from control panel?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I guess I should have mentioned I ran the repair and updated VS which did not fix my problem.  ESRI got back to me and apparently there is a patch some people have required that will fix my problem.  They are supposed to email the patch today, I will post when I have tried this solution.

Comment: Future FYI...ESRI's SDK is pretty picky when it comes to supported Visual Studio versions.  e.g. I have VS 13 Ultimate, ArcObjects v10 wanted me to install VS 2010 C# Express just to code some extensions.  Once it is there, you can run the project in a different version, but it seems like they target specific versions of VS for templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESRI got back to Friday and informed me to run the online service pack 1 installer for VS 2008, even though it indicated that service pack 1 was already installed.  When you check your version, it should be Version 9.0.30729.1 or later in order for the vb SDK to install properly.  Below is a link to the online service pack 1 installer.  I simply ran this, restarted, then installed the SDK with no problems at all.

sp1 installer:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en